# UUID as primary key - REST API guideline

Tags: rest, api, uuid, endpoint

In postgres I created a table:

```
create table examples(id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
                     name VARCHAR);
```

In order to GET all my values from table example i created an endpoint in my framework handler:

```
GET "/examples[/]?"
```

If i was using SERIAL or INT type as my PRIMARY KEY my endpoint for single example value would look like this:

```
GET "/examples/([0-9]+)*"
```

But im using UUID as primary key and i created this monster : P

```
GET "/examples/([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[4][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12})"
```

Use example:

```
examples/ef935fbc-8c43-4b22-b160-14124a29312e
examples/{uuid}
```

It works in my case but is there perhaps a better way to do it ?
Are there any good guidelines that tell how to deal with problems like this?

Comment: Are we talking about verification here? If not, just tell your users it's a string? I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Yea should i somehow check the inputed uuid in my methods before it reaches the database or is the regex i created enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is concerned, using a string representation of a UUID as part of a path segment is fine.  It's just text.  As REST clients just follow links provided to them by the server, it really doesn't matter what spellings are used.

Some choices are going to be easier for your *routing* framework to manage, but your choice of routing is an implementation detail, and not of any concern to consumers of your API.

There's nothing really wrong with using the framework for coarse grained routing, and then implementing the fine grained control yourself

```
GET /examples/{data}

if (isUUID(data)):
    // cast the data to an id yourself, then do the right thing
if "the-other-thing" == data:
    // do the other thing
```